# .remove() only removes the innerHTML NOT the entire tag like I want it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a dynamically created list.  Items from the list should be able to be removed using a delete button.  For some reason, however, it seems to be only deleting the innerHTML NOT the entire tag innerHTML and all, like I want it too.  It possibly has something to do with the selector I am using, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the code.

Thanks in advance!

```
$('#courses').on('click', '.del', function() {
     var tempIndex = $(this).parentsUntil('li').index();
     reducePlanned(myListInfo[tempIndex-1].credits, myListInfo[tempIndex-1].gpa);
     myListInfo.splice(tempIndex-1,1);
     document.getElementById('hrs_planned').innerHTML = '<b>Hours: '+getStringHrs(planned_hrs)+' GPA: '+toStringGPA(planned_gpa)+'</b>    ';
     document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = 'Total Hours: '+getStringHrs(prev_hrs+planned_hrs)+' GPA: '+toStringGPA(((prev_hrs*    prev_gpa)+(planned_hrs*planned_gpa))/(planned_hrs+prev_hrs));
     $(this).parentsUntil('li').remove();
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Are you expecting it to remove the `li` or the `li`'s children?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're expecting it to remove the `li`, the documented behavior of `parentsUntil()` is that it won't touch the `li`.  You need:

```
$(this).parentsUntil('li').parent().remove();
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but I tried it and I can't see any difference.  Any ideas on why this might be?

Comment: Okay after a little bit of fiddling with it I got this to work thank you very much for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

`.parentsUntil()` does not return the element that matches the selector.

You want to call `.closest()` instead.